# Combining 2 select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 select statements having a common column POL.SP_NUM which I wish to combine. I am new to SQL and haven't the slightest clue how to go about with the same.

Query 1:

```
select  POL.SP_NUM POL#
,       POL.ASSET_NUM COV#
,       count(distinct(POLX.ATTRIB_06)) COUNT_ADDENDA
,       count(distinct(POLX.ATTRIB_07)) COUNT_CERT
,       sum(POL.QTY) SI
from    S_ASSET POL
,       S_ASSET_X POLX 
Where   POL.ROW_ID  =   POLX.ROW_ID
and     POL.SP_NUM  in  ('000','111','222')
group by
        POL.SP_NUM
,       POL.ASSET_NUM
```

Query 1 output:

```
POL#    COV#    COUNT_ADDENDA   COUNT_CERT      SI
000     856     2               0               1000
111     123     0               0               500
222     567     0               1               2000
```

Query 2:

```
select POL#, sum(DOCI) 
from    (
            select  POL.SP_NUM POL#, sum(Q.AMT + POL.AMT) DOCI 
            from    S_ASSET POL
            ,       S_QUOTE_ITEM Q 
            where   POL.X_QUOTE_ID  =   Q.ROW_ID 
            and     POL.SP_NUM      in  ('000','111','222')
            group by POL.SP_NUM

            UNION ALL

            select  POL.SP_NUM POL#, sum(QXM.AMT) DOCI 
            from    S_ASSET POL
            ,       S_QUOTE_ITEM Q
            ,       S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM QXM 
            where   POL.X_QUOTE_ID  =   Q.ROW_ID 
            and     Q.ROW_ID        =   QXM.PAR_ROW_ID 
            and     POL.SP_NUM      in  ('000','111','222')
            group by POL.SP_NUM
        )
group by POL#
```

Query 2 output:

```
POL#    sum(DOCI)
000     90
111     0
222     10
```

Desired output:

```
POL#    COV#    COUNT_ADDENDA   COUNT_CERT      SI          sum(DOCI)
000     856     2               0               1000        90
111     123     0               0               500         0
222     567     0               1               2000        10
```

If there is a better way to code this? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: 1) Which database? 2) Please try to avoid comma separated JOINS, they are discouraged now.

Comment: Database: Oracle; I am not sure what you mean by Comma separated JOINS? I wish to combine the select statements into one query with the O/P as displayed above.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: The quickest would be to put both statements in separate WITH clauses, then write regural join on POL# column.

Comment: not very familiar with 'WITH' clause, could share an example please. I was able to achive the desired result using Thorsten's suggestion; but if there is a better/efficient way I am willing to try. Thank u

Comment: Comma-separated joins where used many years ago. `from S_ASSET POL, S_QUOTE_ITEM Q where POL.X_QUOTE_ID = Q.ROW_ID`. Nowadays you'd use explicit joins instead, which where introduced in the SQL Standard 1992. `from S_ASSET POL inner join S_QUOTE_ITEM Q on POL.X_QUOTE_ID = Q.ROW_ID`. They are easier to read, because the join criteria is next to the joined table and is less prone to errors, for you say explicitely what kind of join you want (inner, outer, cross, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge share, could you suggest some link/site which will explain inner/outer/cross joins in a very simple manner (For dummies like me)

Comment: I've added an answer explaining the join types. You may also want to search "sql joins" in Google Images.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just realized that Query 2 in this thread is incorrect. This is the SQLFiddle link "http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29a98/1" where I have set up the tables. Every S_ASSET record will have a record in S_QUOTE_ITEM. There can be one or more records in S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM per S_QUOTE_ITEM(Hence corresponding to S_ASSET). End result grouped by POL#...Union All is not working here :(...I hope I am not annoying you with my sub-zero SQL skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the queries:

```
select *
from (your query 1 here) query1
join (your query 2 here) query2 on query2.pol# = query1.pol#;
```

The same with WITH clauses:

```
with query1 as (your query 1 here),
     query2 as (your query 2 here)
select *
from query1
join query2 on query2.pol# = query1.pol#;
```

Comment: Thank you Thorsten... I was able to get my required output with your suggestion, however I have 2 more select statements (using Cross Join) to combine. Will this method suffice then?

Comment: Well, sure, you can have as many joins as you want. As to Kamil's suggestion to use WITH clauses: that's the same thing only written differently. I'll edit my answer, so you see both and pick whichever you find more readable.

Comment: i'm happy with solution 1, # 2 looks a bit scary :(... but performance impact wise are they the same?

Comment: They are exactly the same. You are just not used to WITH clauses, so they look unfamiliar to you. Many people find them easier to read. But I know how you feel; I don't use them much either :-)

Comment: Your kind response is much appreciated. I have raised another question today "Group By Syntax with Cross Join"; I hope you could spare a few minutes to have a look at the same and assist me (If possible please). Its in the same context as this thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is no answer to the question, but an answer to the request to explain the join types made in the comments setion.

---

**INNER JOIN (or short: JOIN)**

```
 select * from t1 join t2 on t1.colx = t2.coly
```

only gives you matches. This is the most common join. You could replace the ON clause with a USING clause in case the columns in the ON clause have the same names in the tables. Sometimes usefull to quickly write a query, but I would generally not recommend USING.

**LEFT OUTER JOIN (or short: LEFT JOIN)**

```
 select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.colx = t2.coly
```

gives you all t1 records, no matter whether they have a math in t2. So when there is a match or more for a t1 record, then you join these just as wih an inner join, but when a t1 record has no match in t2 then you get the t1 record along with an empty t2 record (all columns are NULL, even the columns you used in the ON clause, which is t2.coly in above example). In other words: you get all records you'd get with an inner join plus all t1 records that have no match in t2.

You can also use a RIGHT JOIN so you'd keep t2 records when there is no t1 match:

```
 select * from t1 right join t2 on t1.colx = t2.coly
```

but this is regarded less readable by many people, so better don't use right outer joins, but simply swap tables then:

```
 select * from t2 left join t1 on t1.colx = t2.coly
```

**FULL OUTER JOIN (or short: FULL JOIN)**

```
 select * from t1 full outer join t2 on t1.colx = t2.coly
```

this gives you all records from both t1 and t2, no matter whether they have a match in the other table or not. Again: You get all records you'd get with an inner join plus all t1 with no t2 match plus all t2 with no t1 match.

When having several full outer joins the USING clause can come in handy:

```
 select product, sum(p1.amount), sum(p2.amount), sum(p3.amount)
 from p1 
 full outer join p2 using (product)
 full outer join p3 using (product);
```

**CROSS JOIN**

A cross join joins a table without any criteria, so as to combine *each* of its records with *each* of the records already present. This is used to get all combinations and usually followed by a left outer join:

```
 select products.product_id, regions.region_id, count(*) 
 from products
 cross join regions
 left join sales on sales.product_id = products.product_id 
                 and sales.region_id = regions.region_id
 group by products.product_id, regions.region_id
 order by products.product_id, regions.region_id;
```

This gives you all possible combinations of products and regions and counts the sales therein. So you get a result record even for product / region combinations where nothing was sold (i.e. no entry in table sales).

**NATURAL JOIN**

looks at common column names to magically join tables. My simple advice: never use this join type.

**ANTI JOIN**

This is not a join type actually, but a usage of a join, namely an outer join. Here you want to get all records from a table *except* the matches. You achieve this by outer-joining the tables and then removing matches in the where clause.

```
 select t1.* 
 from t1 
 left join t2 on t1.colx = t2.coly 
 where t2.coly is null;
```

This looks queer, because we have EXISTS (and IN) to check for existence:

```
 select * 
 from t1 
 where not exists (select * from t2 where t2.coly = t1.colx);
```

So why would one obfuscate things and use the anti join pattern instead? It is a trick used on weak DBMS. When a DBMS is written, joins are the most important thing and the developers of the DBMS put all their effort into making them fast. They may neglect EXISTS and IN at first and only later care about their performance. So it may help then to use a join technique (the anti join) instead. My recommendation: Only use the anti join pattern when running into performance issues with a straight-forward query. So far I've never had to use anti joins it in more than twenty years. (It's good to have that option though. And it's good to know about them, so as to not be confused when stumbling upon such query some time :-)

Comment: Thank you for this. I will definitely try out the queries with real time data. May I ask what motivates you to help out an unknown person?

Comment: That's quite simple: I get much from the Internet and I want to give something back. I am so often so glad to find help on the Internet, and I think it a good idea to share my knowledge, too, so others find help as well. The answers given here don't only help you, but probably also many future readers. This is what makes stackoverflow so great.

Comment: Its only now that I got to read your write-up on Joins. i had initially thought it would be copy-pasted from some where...but I sense that every word is thought up by you and penned down. Hats off for your effort and God bless the generous heart of yours. I do wish I may be able to do something in return...(definitely it wont be advising on SQL ;-))